# how do I find regions that support container services

Tags: ibm-cloud

I am using the BX CLI to create containers service clusters with the bx cs cluster-create. How can I programmatically find the regions that support container services?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the `cf marketplace` command. That command should provide you the information that you seek. The documentation for that command is available here: https://console.bluemix.net/docs/cli/reference/cfcommands/index.html#cf_marketplace

Comment: I issued the "bx cf marketplace" and got the following results:   APIConnect
ATServiceBroker
Auto-Scaling
SecureGateway
WebSphereAppSvr
WorkloadScheduler
cloudantNoSQLDB
compose-enterprise
compose-for-elasticsearch
compose-for-etcd
compose-for-mongodb
compose-for-mysql
compose-for-postgresql
compose-for-rabbitmq
compose-for-redis
compose-for-rethinkdb
compose-for-scylladb
conversation
dashDB
dashDB
db2oncloud
ds_On_Cloud_fyp
g11n-pipeline
imfpush
iotf-service
language_translator
mdm_On_Cloud_fyp
messagehub
personality_insights
speech_to_text
text_to_speech

Comment: tone-analyzer    I don't see the service "Plug-in for the IBM Bluemix Container Service"

Comment: That command is showing you the services and not plug-ins for services.

Comment: So what is the answer to my original question, It appears the command "bx cf marketplace" isn't the answer.

Comment: I asked this question in the containers customer forum and received the following:      so far as I know, there isn't a programmatic way to get that


it's currently supported in us-south (.ng.), eu-central (.eu-de.) and ap-south (.au-syd.)
with uk-south (.eu-gb.) expected in the near future